# How do I append an anchor link to a home link in php/wp?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code and I want to add `#about` to the end of the link

```
<li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>">About Me</a></li>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `#about` like this:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>#about">About Me</a></li>
```

Comment: *smacks forehead, thanks. I'm trying to learn php and I'm over thinking everything